# Discard blocks of data from a table using another table as input

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with measured values for each minute. The first column is the time and it is the primary key of my table. There are no gaps in this time series, so for the timespan of the first row to the last row, I have for each minute exactly one set of measured value. Let this table be named `experiment`. Let the first time be `t_0`, the second be `t_1` and so on...

Now, in another table say `bad_values`, I have a set of bad values that occur sporadically (time is a primary key of `bad_values`too).

Now I want to create a view, say `filtered`, with the following properties: the view should contain the data from `experiment` in time-blocks `t_(10*n)`, `t_(10*n + 1)`, ..., `t(10*[n+1])` of length 10 minutes. Let such a block, for the sake of argument, be named `B_n`. A block `B_n`should be discarded from the view if for any of the time values `t_(10*n)`, ..., `t(10*[n+1])` is contained in `bad_data`.

In other words: I want to filter out time blocks that contain bad data.

My first attempt is to define a table that functions like a mask, i.e. that contains all the times that should be contained in `filtered`.

How does one achieve this (create such a mask) in SQL and particularly SQLite3? Or is the idea t use a mask bad in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore whole blogs you can use the `exists` condition

```
SELECT * FROM experiment e
WHERE not exists (
    SELECT * FROM bad_values b 
    WHERE ((e.time_value - 1) / 10) == ((b.time_value - 1) / 10)
```

by calculating `(time_value - 1) / 10' you get the classes you wanted so only whole classes will be excluded

To get only the good time values you can do it in a single select statement:

```
select time_value from experiment
except
select time_value from bad_values
```

this gives you all the filtered time values you can use this afterwards in in your `FROM` of another query. Or you can use this to insert all the values into a new table, as you wish.

**Edit:**

To delete bad values from the experiment you can simply rund

```
delete from experiment where time_value in (select time_value from bad_values)
```

Comment: This is not the problem. I want to discard blocks of time values if one of them is bad.

Comment: @Sh4pe do you want to delete them from the experiment table? or ignore them in another query? - I understood the later, but if you want to delete them, you can check my updated answer

Comment: I want to delete them eventually, but again I want to delete whole blocks of them (consecutive 10 minute blocks) if one of these vaues in the block is found to be a bad value.

Comment: Ok, sorry I somehow skipped that part - I guess with the `exists` keyword it should work

Comment: This is closer to the solution, but I don't want to delete all measured values that are 10 minutes away from a bad value. I wand to delete only the _block that contains it_. Example: at minute 11 there is a bad value (the only one). I want to _keep_ the block from minute 1 to minute 10, discard the block from minute 11 to minute 20, keep the block from minute 21 to minute 30 and keep all the other blocks... The point is that I want to keep the values from minute 2, 3, .. , 9, 10.

Comment: by calculating `(time_value - 1) / 10' you can get the blocks and can add that condition in the `WHERE` clausal